# Eclipse Plugin folder absolute path

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

how can i get the eclipse plugin folder absolute path through command line or Ant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a singular eclipse plugins folder. There could be multiple installations of Eclipse on the system. Eclipse doesn't store anything globally that would enable one to find these installations. A typical Eclipse installation process is just unzipping a zip file.

I would recommend that you take Eclipse directory as a parameter to your script.

Comment: I thought of that, just wonder it there is a way without involving the user, but i think this is what i will do . Thanks for your replay!